# sp_sent_email - attachment as grid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have quite a big problem with a task which should be easy.
I would like to write a procedure that would send query results by mail as an attachment.

My problem is that the format of attachment is in text, not an grid form.

Using code as below:

```
set @query = 'select 1 as a , 2 as b'

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @profilename
                                   , @recipients = @emailto
                                   , @copy_recipients = @recipients
                                   , @Subject = @SubjectTitle
                                   , @body = @body
                                   , @query = @query 
                                   , @query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv'
                                   , @attach_query_result_as_file = 1
                                   , @query_result_no_padding = 1
```

I get on my email .csv file as per below:

```
a b
- -
1 2

(1 rows affected)
```

While, I would like to have something in the format which would be recognized by excel. So something like that:

```
a,b
1,2
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: Use a different application to send the data. SQL Server only supports sending the data in the text results format if you are attaching them, not CSV. Perhaps you'd be better off with something like SSRS, which supports a multitude of file types.

Comment: You can attach a CSV file using sp_send_dbmail that will open in Excel - but it will fail if you try to open it directly as an attachment.  It has to be saved to the file system first - then Excel will open it with no issues.  There are ways to make it work directly from email - if that is the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

While I totally agree with @Larnu that SQL is - putting this politely - not the best at this, it can be done with ugly queries like

```
SELECT CONCAT('a', ',', 'b')
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(5)),',',CAST(2 AS VARCHAR(5)))
```

Result:

```
a,b
1,2
```

It's also possible to coax SQL into creating valid HTML tables, but it's a lot of string manipulation and very brittle.